# Alert dialog causes my android game to crash

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created an alert dialog to exit my android game. It shows when user click back button and when someone click on YES on alert dialog game crashed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
       getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();

        //shows dialog to quit the game
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null)).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MainActivity.this.finish();

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

}}
```

Comment: any stack trace from logcat?

Answer (score 1):

The crash may be due to bad token exception.
You need to call dialog.dismiss() before activity finish ().

Also if u don't want to take any action when user clicks on "No" then you should not add it to dialog.

Comment: Problem remains same as I use dialog.dismiss(); @PriyaSinghal

Comment: Please provide stack trace fromlogcat

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
     <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/header_logo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: I am trying to edit ques but it gives some error so I posted it on comments sorry for inconvinience